# $ajax, loadin file json.gz from server without compresion enabled, how set headers?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, gzip

my first post here :)

I got json file 'my_data.json'. It's about 3 MB. I  load this with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    'url' : 'my_data.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json){
```

and everything is OK, script gets data from file and I can build a list from them.

Because the size od the file I want to use compression, but my hosting provider has disabled mod_gzip and mod_deflate. So I compressed the file using PHP gzencode and now the file is 250kB only. New file is 'my_data.json.gz'.

When I replace "my_data.json" with "my_data.json.gz" in previous code, nothing happends. I understand that I should inform the browser about the data are compressed. I read about headers and tried to add:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Encoding","gzip");
    },
```

or

```
headers: {"Content-Encoding": "gzip"},
```

after the line

```
dataType: 'json',
```

but nothing happends.

What I'm doing wrong? In what file should I set and what?

Please, point me into right direction.

Comment: Is `my_data.json.gz` the file, or the PHP script that sends it? Are you sure the webserver is configured to run PHP when the file has a `.gz` suffix?

Comment: The `Content-Encoding` header is sent by the server, not the client.

Comment: It's a file. It is not generated dynamically, I send original file once a day and compress it by hand, then I got new file on server (.gz). So I don't know, what it have in common with PHP (I use PHP only for compression and result file is perfectly OK, I checked it and it decompresses).

Comment: @Barmar you wrote:
"The Content-Encoding header is sent by the server, not the client."
So where can I set the header - in .htaccess file?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really that familiar with webserver configuration. From what I can tell by googling, you can use .htaccess to tell it to compress the files, but not to add the header when the file is already compressed. I think you need to use a PHP script to send the file, it can then use the `header()` function to add the header.

Comment: I got answer from my hosting provider and it works prfectly. For anyone who needs this:

.htaccess file should be like this:

`AddEncoding gzip gz
<FilesMatch "\.gz$">
ForceType text/plain
Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
</FilesMatch>`

That's all.

Comment: Answer your own question, don't put the answer in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I got answer from my hosting provider and it works perfectly.
For anyone who needs this:
.htaccess file should be like this:

```
AddEncoding gzip gz
<FilesMatch "\.gz$">
ForceType text/plain
Header set Content-Encoding: gzip
</FilesMatch>
```

That's all.

But if you want to use PHP to send the file instead of .htaccess changing, create new file 'senddata.php' and put this in:

```
<?php $file = 'testowe-dane.json.gz';
if (file_exists($file))
{ header( "Content-Encoding: gzip" );
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit; }
?>
```

then load data from this php file:
`$.ajax({ 'url' : 'senddata.php', dataType: 'json', success: function(json)`
... and so on